# Breeze.js Node.js mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, breeze

I try to get breeze.js into my angular application. My backend is a node.js app that currently stores and gets its models via mongoose.
I don't understand the workflow of breeze on the server side. Do I have to take it in on the server or can I just do my routes as I got it right now? 
I've seen the zza example of the breeze guys and how to get the metadata from the server. 
So is the metadata no my "modeling tool"? 
How would it work if want to secure my data with tokens and for example i put a user into the database and have to create that token on login?

Answer (score 0):

The Breeze client can work with any server that speaks HTTP+JSON.

Some of it's capabilities light up when the server can perform certain tricks. I'm thinking of three in particular

1. server-supplied metadata
2. interpretation of client-defined queries
3. ability to save changes (add/mod/delete) to many entities of multiple types in a single request.

The node/express backend you see in Zza makes use of a Breeze node module, "breeze-mongodb", that can do #2 and #3.

> "breeze-mongodb" is **server** code that "speaks" the language of the Breeze client. It is NOT part of the Breeze client core and you could still write a Breeze client application that talked to a node/mongo backend that did not use this node library.

AFAIK, there is no "breeze-mongoose" module. You are invited to write one and share with the community. Should you accept that mission, you can take "breeze-mongodb" as your model.

> It wouldn't be crazy hard. That module consists of two source files - one for query interpretation and the other for saving changes - each under 500 lines. The syntax differences between raw mongodb and mongoose aren't that great.

The [**Breeze metadata** in Zza](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/node/zza-node-mongo/client/app/services/metadata.js) are constructed by the client application. The "breeze-mongodb" module does not produce metadata. Raw mongoDb doesn't have a notion of schema so there isn't an obvious way that it could generate metadata.

Clearly, if you're using mongoose, you *could* generate metadata (at least a lot of the metadata) from mongoose schema. I'm not sure whether that's worth trying or if it is simply better to let the client create the metadata as we do in Zza.

OTOH, writing a "breeze-mongoose" may be too daunting. Perhaps your app needs only a subset of the query and save features. You could write node/mongoose endpoints that handle just the requests you need.

If you go this route, I recommend switching your client app to the JSON query style and configure the "uriBuilder" to JSON (see [here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-using-json).

> It would still be worth your while to mine the "breeze-mongoose" module for ideas.

**Security** is an orthogonal concern. The Zza example doesn't happen to include any security code. Perhaps it should. It doesn't because it wants to focus on how Breeze works and Breeze itself takes no position on how you secure your data access.

It's up to you to manage identity, guard your server endpoints, and validate data in the manner appropriate for your application. The concepts, tools and libraries for doing so are waiting for you on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try to get more into the system of breeze and will try to figure out a module for mongoose as soon as i find the time for it. Aswell there is a module in development i've seen: https://github.com/ppoliani/breeze-mongoose.